# Xcode - use relative paths instead of direct path for Framework Search Paths

Tags: ios, xcode, path, xcode5

When I add a framework in Xcode (5) it creates this beast of a path:

```
/Users/me/MyApp\ Subfolder1\ Subfolder2/MyApp\ Subfolder1\ Subfolder2/libraries/third-party-lib-2.0
```

How to I turn this direct path into a relative one so that it works wherever the project is opened?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use **$(SRCROOT)** if you want to refer paths relative to your source directory. Refer [this from apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38). There are bunch of these kind of variables. But in Build settings they will be shown as expanded, once you open it for editing it will resort it to the relative path variable.

Between if you are adding frameworks to your project, will be good if you consider using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). Framework/package management will be a piece of cake with it. And the learning curve is also quite smooth.(I don't think if there is a learning curve at all)

Comment: The path you have given is quite confusing for me. Well say you have a directory Libarary in your MyApp folder which contains your project file then the folder Library can be reffered as $(SRCROOT)/Library. Enter this in frameworks path section in Build settings, the paths will expand and you yourself can verify. :)

Comment: @soleil: let me know if thats what you really wanted and if you were able to achieve it.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work is to use ./ and make it recursive.

Comment: @soleil: So did it work with $(SRCROOT) or you couldn't manage it. $(SRCROOT) will point where your project files are. or you can try this. Goto edit scheme in Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme. In there go to arguments and add your path as a variable there. Let me know if it works. Lazy to check it myself. :)

Comment: @soleil: But if this really about framework, i suggest you try your hand in CocoaPods.